# How to highlight radio button when user clicks and only expand the bellow child div?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, radio-button

I have an array of nested objects like below and constructing a tab.

[image]

1. For all the elements key has been given, but even though it is asking key is missing (snapshot provided). Why?

[image]

2. When I click on parent element all the three parent-child are getting expanded, how to restrict to only clicked parent node?

```js
export const tabData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name:"Population",
    col: [
      { ItemCode: 1001, ItemName: "MalePopulation" },
      { ItemCode: 1002, ItemName: "FemalePopulation" },
      { ItemCode: 1003, ItemName: "TotalPopulation" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name:"Poverty",
    col: [
      { ItemCode: 1004, ItemName: "RuralRationShops" },
      { ItemCode: 1005, ItemName: "UrbanRationShops" },
      { ItemCode: 1006, ItemName: "TotalRationShops" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name:"Agriculture",
    col: [
      { ItemCode: 1007, ItemName: "AgriculturalLand" },
      { ItemCode: 1008, ItemName: "NonAgriculturalLand" },
      { ItemCode: 1009, ItemName: "TotalLand" },
    ],
  },
];
```

```js
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

function clickHandler1(e) {
    setOpen(!open);
}

 <div className="h-42 overflow-y-auto">
        {Object.keys(tabdata).map(function (keyName, keyIndex) {
          // console.log(keyName);
          // console.log(tabdata[keyName]);
          
          const col1 = tabdata[keyName].col;
          return (
            <>
              <label key={keyIndex} className="flex flex-row">
                <button
                  key={keyIndex}
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    clickHandler1(e);
                  }}
                  className="flex flex-row"
                >
                  <BiArrowFromTop /> {tabdata[keyName].name}
                </button>
              </label>
              {Object.keys(col1).map(function (keyName1, keyIndex1) {
                return (
                  <>
                    {open && ( 
                      <lable key={col1[keyName1].ItemCode} className="flex flex-row px-6">
                          <Link key={col1[keyName1].ItemCode} 
                          //  href={`gismappage/Year=${yrId}/Chapter=${chpId}/ItemCode=${col1[keyName1].ItemCode}`}> this static goes to ...slug page
                          href={`gismappage?paths=${yrId}/${chpId}/${col1[keyName1].ItemCode}`}>
                          <input
                            name="itm"
                            key={col1[keyName1].ItemCode}
                            type="radio"
                            onClick={() =>
                              clickhandler2(col1[keyName1].ItemCode)
                            }
                          />
                          </Link>
                      {col1[keyName1].ItemName}
                      </lable>
                    )}
                  </>
                );
              })}
            </>
          );
        })}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check box can be solved like

Kept the state variable empty first
onChange event-> taken the radio button value and matched with the value of radio button
if true--> radio button will become checked.

```
 const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");

 function clickHandler2(e, i) {
    alert(e.target.value);
    alert(i);
    setSelected(e.target.value);
  }

<input
      type="radio"
      value={item[keyName1].ItemName}
      checked={item[keyName1].ItemName === selected}
      onChange={(e) =>clickHandler2(e, item[keyName1].ItemName)
      }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of label, I have put the div and provided the key to div element.
as shows in bellow code.

```
<div className="h-42 overflow-y-auto">
    {Object.keys(tabdata).map(function (keyName, keyIndex) {
      // console.log(keyName);
      // console.log(tabdata[keyName]);
     
      const item = tabdata[keyName].items; 
      return (
        <div key={keyIndex}>
          <div className="flex flex-row">
            <button
                onClick={(e) => {
                clickHandler1(e);
              }}
              className="flex flex-row"
            >
              <BiArrowFromTop /> {tabdata[keyName].name}
            </button>
          </div>
          {Object.keys(item).map(function (keyName1, keyIndex1) {
            return (
              <div key={keyIndex1+1}>
                {opn && (
                  <div
                    className="flex flex-row px-6"
                  >
                    <Link
                       //  href={`gismappage/Year=${yrId}/Chapter=${chpId}/ItemCode=${item[keyName1].ItemCode}`}> this static goes to ...slug page
                      href={`gismappage?paths=${yrId}/${chpId}/${item[keyName1].ItemCode}`}
                    >
                      <input
                        name="itm"
                        type="radio"
                        onClick={() =>
                          clickHandler2(item[keyName1].ItemCode)
                        }
                      />
                    </Link>
                    {item[keyName1].ItemName}
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
```

For radio button, I think, I have to keep the active state in useState and handle it.